# Split Django queryset into a many sublists based on a given field

Tags: django, django-views

I have the following model:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Membership', related_name='users')
    date_game = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)


class Membership(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User,  on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('joueur'))
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.IntegerField(_('score'), default=0, validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(50),
            MinValueValidator(0)
        ])
```

I also have this `ListView`, which aims at retrieving all the `Membership` object associated with a `Game` played by a given `User`:

```
class GameListView(ListView):
    model = webapp_models.Membership
    template_name = 'list_games.html'
    form = webapp_forms.UserChoiceField

    def get_queryset(self):

        if self.request.method == 'GET':

            form = self.form(self.request.GET)

            if form.is_valid():
                user = form.cleaned_data['user_choice_field']

                # all games played by the user
                tmp = Game.objects.filter(membership__user=user)

                # all memberships associated to games played by the user
                out = Membership.objects.filter(game__in=tmp)

                for obj in out:
                    print(obj.game.date_game, obj.game.id, obj.user.username, obj.score)

                return out

            return Membership.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, *args, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super(GameListView, self).get_context_data(*args, object_list=None, **kwargs)
        # use the GET data to avoid resetting the form
        context['form'] = self.form(self.request.GET)
        return context
```

I thus would like to split `out` (queryset of `Membership`) into sublists to gather all the `Membership` matching the same `Game`.

Ideally, I would do this in the view rather than in the template.

Comment: So the input is a `Game` and the a `User`...

Comment: `User` is the standard Django user model.

Comment: Looks like you want a sql `group_by` statement. Django ORM currently does not allow that kind of operations, but you can search for the 3rd part library with the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to gather `Membership` objects linked to the same `Game` by means of the `regroup` tag within the template:

```
{% regroup membership_list by game.id as memberships %}
<ul>
{% for group in memberships %}
    <li>{{ group.grouper }}
    <ul>
         {% for m in group.list %}
          <li>{{ m.user.username }}: {{ m.score }}</li>
        {% endfor %}

    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can think about this a little differently.

```
games = Game.objects.filter(membership__user=user).select_related('membership')

for game in games:
     for member in game.members:
          ...do whatever with the members/scores
```

Comment: I get the following error: `Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'membership'. Choices are: (none)`

Comment: It might actually be prefetch_related('membership') here.

Comment: No. I get `Cannot find 'membership' on Game object, 'membership' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()`